# Regularly clone/backup 2 MySQL databases unidirectionally from PC to Laptop both running Windows

Tags: backup, windows, data-synchronization, scheduled-tasks, mysql-4

I have a PC running Windows XP with a custom ERP system and MySQL Server 4.x (A) and a Laptop running Windows 10, same MySQL 4.x and same custom ERP (B). I'm afraid I can't upgrade PC nor MySQL, etc. Can't touch anything.

I installed SQLYog Ultimate (Workbench/Navicat don't like this MySQL version) on laptop and tried scheduling an unidirectional database syncing job from (A) to (B).
**It works**, but **the problem is that SQLYog compares table by table**, and when different, copies record by record and this **takes hours to complete**, because databases to be cloned from (A) are 1.5 and 2 gb each

I've been searching other ways I could setup something in laptop to regularly (once or twice a week through Windows Scheduler) clone a database directly from (A) to (B) without user intervention, but I've run out of ideas.

Any clues? Thanks

Comment: You are aware of [replication](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/en/replication.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up MySQL replication.
In your case, can use the following documentation for version 4.1

http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/en/replication-howto.html

An additional recommendation, upgrade those servers to a newer version.